# No Internet when a modem is on bridged mode

Tags: bridge-router

So I first got the wind of bridge mode on my modem I tried turning it on and connected a ethernet from Lan port 1 -> Wan port of Asus Router which I have only configured the Login Page and Wireless Wifi Name and Password.
Ok so I turned them on the same(like Modem on -> walk to the other router to turn on). It reads as Internet Disconnected or if I turn on fast enough it would display as Dhcp function of main doesn't function properly and goes back as internet disconnected.

Since I browsed the forums earlier, I don't understand what to do.
Do I need to configure another setting and not only the bridge mode option?
I can login to respective webpages option on the modem and router. When I contacted the Isp, to reset the lines and even made it wait the night there is still no Internet connection. Am I still missing something?
Router is Asus RT-AC86U
The setting:
ibb.co/V2gsHJL
ibb.co/vXQBrz8
ibb.co/LY3LtTL
ibb.co/k4rKZb5
ibb.co/rbSsDb6

Comment: Have you got two DHCP servers?  It appears so.

Comment: Do i need to turn off the dhcp server of the modem ? Or the router?

Comment: Now I connected the Modem Lan Port 1 to (disabled dhcp)Asus Router Lan Port 1 and now it can't get an IP Adress (can't  connect to the wireless Wifi)

Comment: Try resetting the ASUS router.  Also consider removing Bridge Mode.

Comment: You can also try connect the WAN port on the ASUS to the WAN port on the modem if in Bridged Mode.

Comment: The setting.    https://ibb.co/V2gsHJL
https://ibb.co/vXQBrz8
https://ibb.co/LY3LtTL
https://ibb.co/k4rKZb5
https://ibb.co/rbSsDb6

Comment: The modem doesnt have wan but only lan so i can only do (modem)lan -> wan(router), but without the dhcp of wan (router) either you can't  connect anymore and no internet. The router doesnt have the red light on wan so I'm not sure whether its the modem or the router that doesnt want to give internet.

Comment: The modem doesnt have wan but only lan so i can only do (modem)lan   .......  I suggest you remove Bridged mode and go back to simpler settings.  I said this in my answer and that is best for you.

Comment: I should mention that I use my ISP modem in Bridged Mode, but the equipment (ISP and Mine) supports Bridged Mode.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have two DHCP servers.

> connected a ethernet from Lan port 1 -> Wan port of Asus Router

Connect a LAN Port on the ASUS Router to a LAN port on the Modem and turn DHCP OFF on the ASUS Router.

You can also connect the WAN port on the ASUS router to the WAN port on the modem (if in Bridged Mode). Done this way, DHCP can remain ON for the ASUS router.

You may wish to get a friend or associate to help you hook this up.

You can also disable (uncheck) Bridged mode and go back to standard settings.